# Generate All customers total Sales Statement - using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have database with `Customers.cs`, `Sales` Here I'm stuck how to Generate All customers total Sales Statement.

Actually I want to calculate All Customers Account Receivables. if I will get that how to generate customers total sales I can generate account receivable report.

**`Sale.cs`**

```
public partial class Sale
{
    public string SaleId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

**`Customer.cs`**

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public string CustId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string TownCity { get; set; }
    public int Contact { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get result like this..

`Town/City`    `CustomerName`    `TotalSale`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your Date and Amount nullable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `GroupBy`:

```
var res = _dbContext.Sales
    .GroupBy(s => s.CustomerId)
    .Select(s => new { CustomerId = s.Key, TotalSales = s.Sum(a => a.Amount) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: throws Error: `System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Project.Sale> does not contain a definition for 'CustomerId' and no extension method 'CustomerId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Project.Sale>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Answer was updated. I missed the `Key` property. Try it again.